# Using master page properties inside aspx code

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I have a master page which contains a property called "LoggedInUserType" and I want to dump this property into the client code to be used with jQuery. I am trying this:

```
$("#headerBar .username").append(" <%=this.LoggedInUserType %>");
```

But it is not showing anything! If instead I try:

```
$("#headerBar .username").append(" <%="Hello" %>");
```

It works fine! Any suggestion what the problem could be?

**EDIT:** I am trying to access the property from the master page itself. That is, the two statements above are to be placed in the master page.

Comment: What is `this.LoggedInUserType`? What type is it, and what does it return?

Comment: Is this jQuery code used inside of DataBound control by any chance ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and not commonly known solution, would be to add this declaration to your ASPX page, just below <@ Page />

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/myMaster.Master" %>
```

Where VirtualPath is the path to your Master File. This will allow you to use stronly typed code below:

```
<%=Master.LoggedInUserType %>
```

Hope this helps,
Kris

**EDIT:**

You say you want to access a Property declared in MasterPage code behind on Master Page itself?
To access your property it needs to be declared as public:

```
public string LoggedInUserType {get; set;}
```

And then you can access it by typing:

```
<%= LoggedInUserType %>
```

Comment: Well, the declaration already exists in my ASPX page. But one thing to note here, I am trying to use the property from the master page itself. I will update the question.

Comment: Ahh I see. Is your property public ?

Comment: Yes, it is. If I make it private, I can't access it in the master page code.

Comment: Could you provide your codebehind snipplet where you declared the Property and a bit of your .Master page where you want to output it please ?

Answer (score 0):

Since it does not throw exception that `LoggedInUserType` property is not found, the only thing could happen is that `LoggedInUserType` has the value of null or empty string.

Check out yourself:

```
$("#headerBar .username").append(" <%= !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.LoggedInUserType) ? this.LoggedInUserType : "EmptyUserType" %>");
```

The question is why is it empty? It depends on how and where `LoggedInUserType` property is being instantiated.

Comment: Good point about the exception. Yes, it doesn't, and if I change the property name, I do get an exception, meaning that the web server is actually seeing the property. However, even when I update the code of the property to return a static string, it doesn't work!! Strange, isn't it?!

Comment: You may have it static, but changing it's value later in Page_Load or elsewhere. Make it `static readonly` and check for any errors appeared.